# Attempting to build for iOS device results in build failure

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a project set up in MonoDevelop, it compiles and runs fine for the simulator but when I try to target a device I get a compile error saying:

> Error 1: mtouch failed with no output (1) (ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch)

And this is the last bunch of stuff the build output has (paste bin: http://pastebin.com/Ea8hgaFH):

> Compiling to native code /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v
>   --nomanifest --nosign -dev
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app"
>   "-r=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/ExEn/ExEnEmTouch/bin/iPhone/Debug/ExEnEmTouch.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/ExEn/ExEnCore/bin/iPhone/Debug/ExEnCore.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1
>   XNA/bin/iPhone/Debug/FarseerPhysics.dll"
>   "-r=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/Content/Jabber.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/OpenTK.dll"
>   "-r=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.Linq.dll" -debug
>   "-sdk=4.3" -cxx -gcc_flags
>   "-L/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/box2D/JabberWorx
>   -lBox2D -force_load
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/box2D/JabberWorx/libBox2D.a"
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens.exe"
>   Framework is:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk
>   Copied
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens.exe
>   to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ChicksnVixens.exe
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/mscorlib.dll
>   Copied
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/ExEn/ExEnCore/bin/iPhone/Debug/ExEnCore.dll
>   to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ExEnCore.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Mono.Security.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/monotouch.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Core.dll
>   Copied
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/ExEn/ExEnEmTouch/bin/iPhone/Debug/ExEnEmTouch.dll
>   to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ExEnEmTouch.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/OpenTK.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/OpenTK.dll
>   Copied
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/Content/Jabber.dll
>   to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Jabber.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.Linq.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll
>   Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Xml.dll
>   Copied /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/Farseer Physics Engine
>   3.3.1 XNA/bin/iPhone/Debug/FarseerPhysics.dll to
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/FarseerPhysics.dll
>   Linking assembly
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens.exe
>   into
>   /Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/System.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/ExEnCore.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ExEnCore.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/monotouch.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/monotouch.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/OpenTK.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/OpenTK.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/ChicksnVixens.exe.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ChicksnVixens.exe"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/System.Xml.Linq.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/mscorlib.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/mscorlib.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/Jabber.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Jabber.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/ExEnEmTouch.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/ExEnEmTouch.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/FarseerPhysics.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/FarseerPhysics.dll"
>   Compilation exited with code 134, command:
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/Jabber.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Jabber.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Mono.Security.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/System.Xml.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Xml.dll"
>   MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug
>   --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmp508a6b37.tmp/System.Core.dll.6.s
>   "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/System.Core.dll"
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------

I'm pretty certain I've set up my certificates and provisioning profile correctly. The only other thing I can think that could be causing this is that this project was originally located on another install of OSX..

Any ideas?

Comment: This is extremely difficult to read since all new lines were removed. Can you edit the log ? or add a pastebin link ? or fill a bug report (and attach or paste the log) ?

Comment: done, paste bin here: http://pastebin.com/Ea8hgaFH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **134** can come from several, different issues.

```
Compilation exited with code 134, command:
```

1) it could be a linker issue.

Try "Don't Link" to see if your build works (or not). If it works then try adding a few more **-v -v** to get some additional information on your exact build issue.

Ref: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=144

2) you could try adding the **-nosymbolstrip** argument

Ref: http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Troubleshoot#Error_134.3a_mtouch_failed_with_the_following_message.3a

3) you're not using LLVM so I do not think this will apply: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=164

4) you're using the [MonoPInvokeCallback(Type)] attribute on a non-static method. This is not supported by MonoTouch

Ref: http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Limitations?highlight=MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute#Reverse_Callbacks

In any case the **134** error looks related to **Jabber.dll**

```
Compilation exited with code 134, command:
MONO_PATH=/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug --aot=full,static,asmonly,soft-debug,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/k1/0cqbnjsd1710x4mbyvdsn1tw0000gp/T/tmpa4e996f.tmp/Jabber.dll.6.s "/Users/dev/Documents/Proj/cnv/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/bin/iPhone/Debug/ChicksnVixens-MonoTouch.app/Jabber.dll"
```

so your best bet (the above does not work) is to fill a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach the Jabber.dll binary (and any assemblies it refers). We'll try to duplicate your issue.

Comment: damn, neither option 1 or 2 worked :-/ submitted a bug report with Jabber.dll attached.

Comment: a wild guess (while I'm rebuilding all the code to debug this properly) but could you be using an instance (non-static) method for your reverse callback ? 

Ref: "The methods have to be static methods, there is no support for instance methods (this limitation will be removed in the future)." from http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Limitations?highlight=MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute#Reverse_Callbacks

Comment: edited the above answer (since my guess was right) to include a fourth condition to check

Comment: yep it is building now. Sadly now there's another issue I'm trying to deal with but it appears to have more to do with the actual static library :-/ so close to seeing it run on a device yet so far!

Comment: actually would you know why it ran in the simulator but wouldn't compile for the device?

Comment: It was on the bug report can I can repeat here for everyone's benefit :-). The simulator uses the JIT (not AOT) in order to give users (much) faster edit/build/debug cycles. On the device JITting is not possible, so the AOT compiler must be used (every time). AOTing brings some additional restrictions (including the one on the reverse callbacks) since everything must be known at compile (not run) time.